# How do we know that $y=e^{-\int P(x)dx}(c+\int e^{P(x)dx}f(x)dx)$ is the general solution of $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=f(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

It is straightforward that any function of the form $y=e^{-\int P(x)dx}(c+\int e^{P(x)dx}f(x)dx)$  is a solution of the differential equation on the interval $I$ for which $P$ and $f$ are continuous. However, how are we sure that if $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=f(x)$ has a solution, then it must be of the form $y=e^{-\int P(x)dx}(c+\int e^{P(x)dx}f(x)dx)$ ?

The book used variation of parameters to arrive at this solution. How can we show that there is no other solution other than the one obtained using variation of parameters?

Comment: If there are two solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$, then the difference $y_1-y_2$ satisfies the diff. eq. $dy/dx=-P(x)y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That essentially follows from the *linearity* of the equation.

If you have a linear differential operator $L$ and the inhomogeneous equation $Lu=f$, then for any two solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$ that satisfy $Lu_1=f$ and $Lu_2=f$, you have by linearity
$$
L(u_1-u_2)=0
$$
which means, the difference $u_1-u_2$ is a solution to the homogeneous equation $Lu=0$.

---

In your example, $(Lu)(x)=\frac{du}{dx}+P(x)u(x)$.

Your solution is written as $u=u_h+u_p$, where

The part $u_h(x):=Ce^{-\int P(x)dx}$ is the general solution to $Lu=0$ and $u_p$ is a particular solution to $Lu=f$ found by some method (say, variation of parameters).

If you find another particular solution $u_q$ to the equation $Lu=f$, then $$
u_q-u_p=Ke^{-\int P(x)dx}
$$
for some constant $K$. So solution to $Lu=f$ is still of the form $u=u_h+u_p$.